# PHP and SQL binding values as string instead of integers returning syntax error at the console

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have the following query:

```
$stmt = $this->db_con->prepare(
    SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.username from repair_dealer d
    WHERE d.user_id=:u_id
    ORDER BY d.date_added DESC
    LIMIT :pageIndex, :pageSize
) 

$stmt->bindValue(':u_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':pageIndex', $pageIndex, PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':pageSize', $pageSize, PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

The values are sent from ionic as numbers, but I am having the following php-sql error at the console:

> message: "ERROR : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''0', '15'' at line 16"

0 and 15 are the limits

I tested out this query on my server and it returned data.

Comment: where do you declare u?

Comment: Are the values strings or integers? I'd cast them

Comment: values sent from ionic as `numbers` they are declared in ionic as numbers